# miner.start(1) triggers but not starting the mining

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, mining, private-blockchain, geth-debugging

I am creating my own private ethereum blockchain.

```
sudo geth --rpcapi eth,web3,personal --rpc --networkid=15
```

Above command gives the below logs.

```
INFO [09-18|10:16:42.151] Maximum peer count                       ETH=25 LES=0 total=25
INFO [09-18|10:16:42.153] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.8.15-stable-89451f7c/linux-amd64/go1.10
INFO [09-18|10:16:42.153] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/blockchain/.ethereum/geth/chaindata cache=768 handles=512
INFO [09-18|10:16:42.171] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 1 Homestead: 1150000 DAO: 1920000 DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2463000 EIP155: 2675000 EIP158: 2675000 Byzantium: 4370000 Constantinople: <nil> Engine: ethash}"
INFO [09-18|10:16:42.171] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=/home/blockchain/.ethereum/geth/ethash count=3
INFO [09-18|10:16:42.171] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=/home/blockchain/.ethash               count=2
INFO [09-18|10:16:42.171] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=15
INFO [09-18|10:16:42.173] Loaded most recent local header          number=0 hash=d4e567…cb8fa3 td=17179869184
INFO [09-18|10:16:42.173] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0 hash=d4e567…cb8fa3 td=17179869184
INFO [09-18|10:16:42.173] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=0 hash=d4e567…cb8fa3 td=17179869184
INFO [09-18|10:16:42.174] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=0 dropped=0
INFO [09-18|10:16:42.174] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [09-18|10:16:42.174] Starting P2P networking
INFO [09-18|10:16:46.891] UDP listener up                          self=enode://e919e98154dcddc4e6e6f847332795cbaf072607e410c2330702d3b66b4219eb98c4ebf39dc1ee2b21af74049926a5fb646542636f8835eb420157d825cc3102@[::]:30303
INFO [09-18|10:16:46.892] RLPx listener up                         self=enode://e919e98154dcddc4e6e6f847332795cbaf072607e410c2330702d3b66b4219eb98c4ebf39dc1ee2b21af74049926a5fb646542636f8835eb420157d825cc3102@[::]:30303
INFO [09-18|10:16:46.896] IPC endpoint opened                      url=/home/blockchain/.ethereum/geth.ipc
INFO [09-18|10:16:46.897] HTTP endpoint opened                     url=http://127.0.0.1:8545               cors= vhosts=localhost
INFO [09-18|10:16:59.561] Etherbase automatically configured       address=0xa76D511FCddEB3bCCa1Eb5B6bf4EC39a8d95668d
```

Then i trigger `miner.start(1)` by getting geth console using `sudo geth attach ../.ethereum/geth.ipc` so it adds below lines in above logs.

```
INFO [09-18|10:18:06.859] Updated mining threads                   threads=1
INFO [09-18|10:18:06.860] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=1000000000
INFO [09-18|10:18:06.860] Commit new mining work                   number=1 sealhash=d91037…57fc0d uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed=648.451µs
```

And after this nothing happens.

FYI,  `miner.start(1)` returns `null` but that is not a problem i guess.

Could you please give me some hints so that i can do possible workarounds to make mining start.

Comment: Your node is apparently misconfigured. indeed if you take a look at the logs, you can see that it uses the main chain (ChainID=1) and not the networkid you are specifying. Do you already created the DAG before mining? (Usually, it requires some time).

Comment: Yes @Briomkez it took lot of time actually.

Answer (score 1):

The comment from @Briomkez is a correct start - when running the geth command, it is showing that you've connected to `ChainID: 1` which is not correct - it's not your private network.

To start a private network, create your genesis file (I like to use puppeth).

Once you've created your genesis file, run geth init, importantly here - define a datadir

`geth --datadir test init ./testpow.json`

This will "create a database that uses this genesis block, run the following command. This will import and set the canonical genesis block for your chain" -
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Private-network

Now run the same command you included above, but again include the datadir here ->

`geth --datadir test --rpcapi eth,web3,personal --rpc --networkid=15`

when you run this command - it will show you the ipc file that is being used across from the line item:

[image: ipc opened]

Make sure you use this IPC when you run `geth attach`

Once in the console - assuming you have an account created and unlocked you can run `miner.start(1)` otherwise you may need to run `personal.newAccount` to create an account for mining before `running miner.start(1)`

You can also use these flags to start mining from your geth command `-unlock '0xaddress' --password ./password.txt --mine`

Answer (score 0):

you can try use this command(rm -rf $HOME/.ethash) before your start the geth. [here is detail](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2174)

Comment: already tried that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows with a custom datadir like I am.  It turns out the Ethash still lives here: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData.  My resolution was to delete the contents of this directory, instead of my datadir.  There may be an equivalent in a linux environment.  Reference your IPC Channel startup feedback:

`[2019.02.19-11:16:04.464350]: INFO [02-19|11:16:02] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.7.3-stable-4bb3c89d/windows-amd64/go1.9.
[2019.02.19-11:16:04.474094]: INFO [02-19|11:16:02] Allocated cache and file handles         database=C:\\DTS\\Ledgers\\1111\\Ledger\\geth\\chaindata cache=128 handles=1024.
[2019.02.19-11:16:04.485756]: INFO [02-19|11:16:02] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 1111 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: <nil> EIP155: 0 EIP158: 0 Byzantium: <nil> Engine: unknown}".
[2019.02.19-11:16:04.491861]: INFO [02-19|11:16:02] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=C:\\DTS\\Ledgers\\1111\\Ledger\\geth\\ethash count=3.
[2019.02.19-11:16:04.497462]: INFO [02-19|11:16:02] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData\\Ethash count=2.
[2019.02.19-11:16:04.503220]: INFO [02-19|11:16:02] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=1111.
[2019.02.19-11:16:04.508075]: INFO [02-19|11:16:02] Loaded most recent local header          number=0 hash=95ae19â€¦a63ec2 td=0.
[2019.02.19-11:16:04.512925]: INFO [02-19|11:16:02] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0 hash=95ae19â€¦a63ec2 td=0.
[2019.02.19-11:16:04.518492]: INFO [02-19|11:16:02] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=0 hash=95ae19â€¦a63ec2 td=0.
[2019.02.19-11:16:04.523792]: INFO [02-19|11:16:02] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=1 dropped=0.
[2019.02.19-11:16:04.528894]: INFO [02-19|11:16:02] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=1 accounts=1.`

> Specifically notice:
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Ethash